# How can i read txt file and convert it to xlsx file with this type of code

Tags: python, python-3.x

when trying to open the excel file it gives an error: excel not able to open the file because file format or file extension is not valid

```
import openpyxl
with open('fruits.txt') as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()
with open("output2.xlsx",  "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(content)
```

Comment: you are passing a ".txt" file where is the excel file ?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use csv for this. Open the txt file as usual from file read methods of Python and then use csv for writing it into a file of type csv(you will get the feel of excel file only). Do not use openpyxl to open a file of txt extension.

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way i could go straight from txt file to xlsx file?

Comment: If you do want to get in excel, then you can use pandas library for that. You can read a csv file as pd.read_csv(csv_file_name) and conver it into excel using pd.to_excel(excel_file_name,'Sheet1'). But i would prefer you can work with csv only, it will serve the same purpose.